# Open .html file onClick JavaScript / React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react to create a website, and I have the resume.html file stored in the website's src directory. I want to open a new tab and display the resume.html file in that new tab when I click the "Resume" button. The following code does not work. I've looked all over for an answer but I cannot figure it out. Thank you!

`<Resume onClick={window.open("./resume.html", "_blank")}>View My Resume</Resume>`

Comment: try keeping resume.html in a  public folder

Comment: @Freddy I tried that. Still nothing

Comment: try this `<Resume onClick={()=>window.open("./resume.html", "_blank")}>View My Resume</Resume>`

Comment: @Pigeon16 check out this https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-glade-l8dwm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I can see it working on the sandbox. I recreated it exactly but I cannot get it to work on my localhost project. Weird

Comment: Never Mind. I figured it out @Freddy, Thanks!